# Sql select newest date

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I am trying to make a view with the following code...

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
                     TOP (100) PERCENT .dbo.InventoryItems.ItemNo, .dbo.InventoryItems.ItemID, .dbo.InventoryItems.DescriptionMed, 
                     .dbo.PODetails.MostRecentCost, .dbo.UOMs.UOMCode, .dbo.PODetails.BuyUOMID, .dbo.UOMConvert.Factor, 
                     .dbo.PODetails.MostRecentCost * .dbo.UOMConvert.Factor AS [Price Test], .dbo.PO.EntryDate, 
                     .dbo.UOMConvert.UOMID

FROM            .dbo.PO INNER JOIN
                     .dbo.PODetails ON .dbo.PO.POID = .dbo.PODetails.POID INNER JOIN
                     .dbo.UOMConvert INNER JOIN
                     .dbo.UOMs ON .dbo.UOMConvert.ToUOMID = .dbo.UOMs.UOMID INNER JOIN
                     .dbo.InventoryItems ON .dbo.UOMConvert.ItemID = .dbo.InventoryItems.ItemID ON 
                     .dbo.PODetails.ItemNo = .dbo.InventoryItems.ItemNo
ORDER BY .dbo.PO.EntryDate DESC
```

that gives me all records sorted by the Entrydate but I am only looking to keep the newest record for each ItemNo. I have tried adding group by statements, row numbers and a MAX() statement  but I must be entering all of them in wrong as they are all giving me errors due to my limited knowledge of SQL. :( Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use `window function`.

```
select * from (
select row_number()over(partition by itemno order by Entrydate desc) Rn,
       .... 
from table1 join ...)
A where rn=1
```